# checking the preview of converted servlet from jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am new bie to the world of j2ee but I am still learning it , I have read the servlets and going through JSP as I have found that JSP also ultimately converted in to servlet by web container, is there any tool online tool or something in which it can show me also the preview of jsp converted into servlet itself , Just a snapshot, although I know I can check that same also in webserver folder also.! Please advisee

Answer (score 0):

no need of any tool if u r using **tomcat** u can directely see jsp equalent servlet

**Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\work\Catalina\localhost**

here .java && .class directely available

it is also possible for most of the servers